# Why is "dessin" pronounced like "déssin"?

Tags: prononciation, orthographe, diacritiques, voyelles

One of the things that I appreciate as a French learner is that words in French are so easy to pronounce. Unlike in English, where letters can be pronounced many different ways, and you have no way of knowing other than by being familiar with the word (for example, all these words are pronounced differently: cough, tough, bough, though, through), French instead seems to only have one pronunciation for each letter or vowel-letter-pair.

However, the pronunciation of "dessin" surprises me. It sounds like "déssin" instead of the first vowel sounding like "de", as I would have expected.

1. Is there a pronunciation rule for "dessin" that applies to other words, or is it only for the word "dessin"?
2. Historically, why is this one of the exceptions, where "de" isn't always pronounced the same?

Comment: French is far more regular than English in this department, but it's not perfectly regular; compare *fils* "son" and *fils* "threads", with different pronunciations. Unfortunately, I don't know the answer for *dessin*.

Comment: @LukeSawczak: as an FSL, seeing such counterexamples does help my brain twist itself to become more flexible / adapted to this new language. thanks for the "fils" example.

Comment: [Courteline, starting at the bottom of p.84](https://books.google.ca/books?id=CyjAU_TU-6IC&pg=PA84&lpg=PA84#v=onepage&q&f=false), a poet that made himself a humorist for a moment, and [Allais](http://poesie.webnet.fr/lesgrandsclassiques/poemes/alphonse_allais/rimes_riches_a_l_oeil.html), a humorist who occasionally played with rhymes, both had a go at having the irregularities of French sticking out in hilarious un-rhyming verses.

Comment: I'm going to upvote this question cause it had me realize I may have prounounced it wrong my whole life...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule is that "e" is pronounced "é" or "è" when in the middle of a syllable, and "e" (like in "de") when at the end of a syllable. Syllables always split double letters, so we have "des-sin", and the first "des" is pronounced just like the word "des".

Comment: so there is no way to know if, when pronounced like "é" or "è"', which of these two it more likely will be (for most french-speaking people)?

Comment: I can say that usually when this is the last pronounced syllable, it is "è" ("presse") and when there's another pronounced syllable after it seems to be "é" ("pression") but that might differ among accents or words.

Comment: I think "è" can always be used. For example it's given as a possible pronounciation in "pression" here https://fr.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/pression

Answer (score 7):

1. Yes silph, there is a rule: when the "e" is followed by a pair of consonants, you say "é" like in "d**ess**in, pr**ess**ion" or "è" like in "b**ell**e, bret**ell**e, parisi**enn**e, gu**err**e"...
2. Well, because it's french :P and there are lot of exceptions about etymology and word evolution through ages.

Comment: I pronounce the e in pression like an è, not an é.

Comment: What about the words **des**, **mes**, **tes**, **ses**, **les**... These words aren't followed by a pair of consonants and are pronounced "é".

Comment: @georges619 <es> in monosyllabic words is always é or è, that's another predictable rule. What isn't is predicting whether the e will be open (è) or closed (é), because that will differ by dialect. I have è in all the words cited in the answer, as well as des, mes, etc.

Comment: That said, the sequence <ess> is ambiguous because sometimes the <ss> will be used to indicate /s/ instead of /z/, but the preceding e is still mute, for example *ressac* (/ʀəsak/, not /ʀɛsak/). Compare with *reserrer* (/ʀəsɛʀe/, not /ʀəzɛʀe/)

Comment: Indeed; this is not just a phonological question but a morphophonological one.

Comment: @Eauquidort : "ressaler" is the same case. (re + saler) It's one of those cases where the intention of adding the "re" prefix take precedence over spelling tyranny. ("parasol", "présélection")

Answer (score 0):

There is a rule for accenting.

When trying to accent an "e", you'll write "è" whenever the vowel in the following syllable is a single "e" that's either deaf or is pronounced "e", and you'll write "é" otherwise (ignoring the circumflex case).

That's for consistency reasons with this rule that the 1990 reform corrected "événement" into "évènement", changed the accenting in the future tense ("céder + ai" now is written "cèderai" instead of "céderai"), and in those unused "dussé-je" now written "dussè-je".

The two-identical consonants in "dessin" are preventing the accenting of the "e", but the pronunciation is consistent with the accenting rule.

Answer (score 0):

Accent sur *E* : **É** ou **È** ?

— *E* dernière lettre d’un mot : **É**

> « Liberté, Égalité, Fraternité ».

— *E* à la fin d’un mot et suivi d’un **s** au singulier : **È**

> décès, après.

— si la syllabe suivante contient un **e** muet : on prononce le *E* : **È**, sinon il si prononce **É**, et on supprime l’accent si le *E* est suivi de deux consonnes

> **È** : La guerre est mère de douleurs.
>
> **É** : Des dessins dépouillés.

— **Ê** et **Ë** sont des **E** accentués qui observent d’autres règles.